# Github actions error - Process exited with status 1

Tags: github, deployment, github-actions, continuous-deployment

```
  prepare-release-on-servers:
    name: "${{ matrix.server.name }}: Prepare release"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: create-deployment-artifacts
    strategy:
      matrix:
        server: ${{ fromJson(needs.create-deployment-artifacts.outputs.deployment-matrix) }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: app-build

    - name: Upload
      uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
      with:
        host: ${{ matrix.server.ip }}
        username: ${{ matrix.server.username }}
        key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
        port: ${{ matrix.server.port }}
        source: ${{ github.sha }}.tar.gz
        target: ${{ matrix.server.path }}/artifacts
```

I have the above file set up for deployment with github actions but I get the following error message:

```
$ tar all files into /tmp/1572874449/LrdzhrdahF.tar
$ tar -cf /tmp/1572874449/LrdzhrdahF.tar 5582b2e863bad1ad97bf662193b090b7e1dbaf85.tar.gz
scp file to server.
2022/09/30 12:15:55 error copy file to dest: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, error message: Process exited with status 1
drone-scp error:  error copy file to dest: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, error message: Process exited with status 1
```

I have enabled the debug but still no clear message of the issue. If i use from my local the same key works perfectly. any idea would be very appreciated . Am I doing something wrong here? Or am i missing something?

Comment: Is the host you are trying to connect to a publicly available host?

Comment: yes, i don't have a specific setting in my local.

Comment: after change of the server, i can see in the logs that there is something like this: ```Sep 30 17:52:14 server3 sshd[3352024]: Connection closed by authenticating user *** 20.242.31.175 port 1408 [preauth]``` . why is this on port 1408?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the hosting company. They do not allow any writing in the `/home` directory.

In order to fix this you need to specify in the GitHub actions file, under the environment, the root path:

```
env:
  HOST: ....
  ROOT_PATH: /home/....
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case,

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/
```

was the solution.